# Importing a .ipynb file as a module to another python file

Tags: python, module

I have a file called orbital.ipynb (in jupyter notebooks) .

I'm currently working on a new file called OrbitalStockSelector , and I'd like to import the orbital.ipynb file to the new file.

I've tried changing the extension to .py , using import_module(orbital) but have not been able to succeed. I get:

```
 ImportError: No module named orbital
```

Comment: `.ipynb` files are *not python source code*, you will have to convert it into source-code.

Answer (score 0):

`.ipynb` files are not valid python modules.  They use a custom format to store the code and output.  To use your code, you would need to move it to a valid `.py` file that is [importable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-importing)

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: I used !ipython nbconvert --to=python config_template.ipynb
 in the notebook